# Write a case to display a new field in a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view, where there is a `head_fullname` field (first name last name of directors), the way to find this field is indicated in the case of view:

```
case
   when p.dep_id  <> 'MM' then
     case
       when p.man_id = '######' then
         'Special name'
       when m2.man_login is not null then
          c2.last_name || ' ' || c2.fst_name || ' ' || c2.mid_name
       else
          c3.last_name || ' ' || c3.fst_name || ' ' || c3.mid_name
       end
       else
          o.head_fullname
end as head_fullname
```

I want to join the `q_employee` table to the view, where there are `fullname` and `login` fields, in order to add a new field `head_login` (directors logins) to the view. And how can I use the case that I indicated above to write a condition so that `head_fullname` from the view is equal to `fullname` from `q_employee` then output `login` as `head_login`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option (from my point of view, that is) is to use your current query view as a CTE (or a subquery) and join it to the new table which provides login information.

Something like this:

```
create or replace view whatever_name_it_is
as
-- this is your current view query
with current_view_query as
  (select ...,
     case when p.dep_id <> 'MM' then
        ...
     end as head_fullname,
   ...
   from ...
   where ...
  )
-- now, join current view query (in a form of a CTE) with Q_EMPLOYEE  
select c.*, e.head_login
from current_viwe_query c join q_employee e on c.head_fullname = e.fullname
```